# ConcatRelated returns multiple lines per record ID

Tags: sql, ms-access

I made a query in Access 2003 using ConcatRelated to return a string of all children per each parent.  However, my test query is returning multiple identical lines - one for each child.  So the SQL:

```
SELECT Moms.MomID, Moms.MomLast, 
    ConcatRelated("KidFirst","KidsAgeQ","MomID =" & kidsageq.MomID) AS Kids
FROM Moms INNER JOIN KidsAgeQ ON Moms.MomID = KidsAgeQ.MomID;
```

returns the following:

**MomID - MomLast - Kids**

34 . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . Pippin, Sunshine, Rose

34 . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . Pippin, Sunshine, Rose

34 . . . . . . Q . . . . . . . Pippin, Sunshine, Rose

Is this normal?  And whether it's normal or not, how do I fix it to return  only a single record for each MomID?

Comment: Try changing `SELECT` TO `SELECT DISTINCT`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you get multiple rows per `MomID` due to the `INNER JOIN` with `KidsAgeQ`.  You shouldn't need to include that table in order to retrieve the concatenated `KidFirst` values matching each `MomID`.

If this query doesn't give you the result you need, please show us sample data from `Moms`.

```sql
SELECT
    m.MomID,
    m.MomLast, 
    ConcatRelated("KidFirst","KidsAgeQ","MomID =" & m.MomID) AS Kids
FROM Moms AS m;
```